# Identical match (with type checking) in switch statement PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement, equality

Just found a strange situation where we need to run `switch` statements only on identical match (with exact type). Just think about this scenario:

```
$value = "";

switch ($value) {
    case 0:
        echo "Zero";
        break;

    case 1:
        echo "One";
        break;

    case "":
        echo "Empty";
        break;

    default:
        echo "None";
        break;
}
```

This will `echo` **"Zero"** where I want it to `echo` **"Empty"**. Is this possible to do in some way with `switch` statement or I have the only way to use `if...elseif...else` with `===` operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this

```
$value = "";

switch (true) {
    case ($value === 0):
        echo "Zero";
        break;

    case ($value === 1):
        echo "One";
        break;

    case ($value === ""):
        echo "Empty";
        break;
}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/tb0H4X)**</kbd>

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but it still serves the purpose better than going with `if...elseif...else`. I will accept this, if no other better alternative found by next answers! Thanks.

Comment: Dhonnobad :) @TareqMahmood

Answer (score 5):

PHP's switch statement is [documented to use loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). If you need exact matches, then unfortunately, the best bet is to use separate if/else tests with `===`.

One alternative is something similar to

```
switch(true) {
    case $value === 0:
        //...
        break;
}
```

but that's about the same as a series of if-else statements, with more typing and indentation.

Comment: It's true that it has more indentation and slightly more typing, but I think it's cleaner and more readable than `if....elseif...else` statements! Anyways, thanks for mentioning about the "loose comparison", I missed that when checking the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, you just need to flip what you are comparing:

```
switch(true) { 
    case $value === 0:
    echo "Zero";
    break;

    case $value === 1:
    echo "One";
    break;

    case $value === "":
    echo "Empty";
    break;

    default:
    echo "None";
    break;
}
```